# 3 Total posts awaiting review

Tags: support

In my status bar on Arduino stackexchange (not meta) I see in the top bar a square, brown with 3 in it and hovering shows: 3 total posts awaiting review.

However, if I look in the review list, all reviews show 0 items (including from meta data).

Where can I find these 3 posts?

I see this since I just got over 2,000 reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That used to happen to me too. There is some explanation along the lines that you recently reviewed something so it is dropped from the list, but the count on the top bar is a cached one.

See:

- [Queue counts inconsistent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288767/queue-counts-inconsistent)
- [Review counts in top-bar and /review don't match](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match)
- [Answer for Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/297719)